# Click to ROOT even without PC? How is this possible?

Tags: applications, rooting, root-access, kingo

There are many apps which says you can root in single click, like framaroot, one click root, kingo root.
I'm not sure whether everythings works, but, YouTube videos claim that.
How these apps root a phone with just a single click?
If a app can root a phone with a click, it can also do that without the knowledge of a user.
So, How do these apps work?

Comment: Those one-click-root apps are usually pretty old as most of the used exploits were only present in Android 4.x and 5.x. Hence on newer devices they are useless. Therefor look at the compatibility list and the list of supported Android versions of each app.

Comment: https://autoroot.chainfire.eu/ this says android till 7.0 are compatible. Is security patches are released for these exploits. Do you have any external source for reading.

Comment: But on the linked page there are only odin/fastboot flashable images (hence both require a PC and an unlocked device), no app based rooting if I have not missed something.

Comment: currently i am just aware of one app (which i don't mention because it is based on top of others work and violates the copyleft of the original author of the underlaying binary) How these exploits work? https://www.xda-developers.com/mediatek-su-rootkit-exploit